# Como saber o tamanho em Kb de uma string?

Tags: delphi, xml, windows, delphi-7

Eu tenho um `string` que será salva em arquivo **xml**, e este arquivo não pode ser maior que **500 kb**.

1. Como posso identificar o tamanho da `string` que irei salvar em arquivo **xml**?
2. Quando a `string` for salva no arquivo **xml**, a mesma pode mudar de tamanho com a adição de informações do Windows?
   Por exemplo: Data de Criação do Arquivo e etc...

Comment: Veja se [esse site](http://www.planetadelphi.com.br/dica/7507/-tamanho-de-um-arquivo-em:-b,-kb,-mb-e-gb-) pode lhe ajudar.

Comment: @SamirBraga Ajuda em parte. A dica do artigo informado explica como verificar o tamanho de um arquivo. Porém, eu preciso verificar o tamanho de uma determinada **String** que ainda vou salvar em arquivo xml.

Comment: Para verificar se um arquivo maior que 500kb obedece à regra, você precisa primeiro criar este arquivo...

Comment: Para saber que tamanho o arquivo vai ficar, basta contar o tamanho da string em bytes, usando Length. Não há necessidade de criar fisicamente uma cópia em disco. Aliás, se o arquivo vai ser enviado, como uma NFe, por exemplo, pode muito bem ser armazenada uma cópia local numa base de dados, e a string do XML ser enviada diretamente à SEFAZ (criar um arquivo intermediário é totalmente desnecessário).

Comment: Normalmente não é recomendado fazer duas ou mais perguntas juntas quando elas não interferem uma na outra. Fica difícil de você escolher a melhor resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Se você está utilizando o Delphi 7 (conforme a tag), basta medir utilizando o método `Length` e ele vai lhe dar o tamanho em Bytes.

Mas isso logo pode lhe causar problemas caso atualize seu Delphi para uma versão que utiliza Unicode. Um meio que estaria a prova de atualizações é utilizar `Length(S) * SizeOf(Char)` que também lhe dará o valor em bytes.
Exemplo de código abaixo:

```
function TamanhoEmBytes(Const strAMedir: String): integer;
begin
  Result := Length(S) * SizeOf(Char);
end;
```

Mais sobre o assunto:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38693

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529992/delphi-unicode-string-length-in-bytes

2) As informações como data de acesso e dada de criação do arquivo, bem como permissões são armazenadas de acordo com o sistema de arquivos da partição onde o arquivo foi armazenado. Assim dependerá de onde o arquivo for armazenado. No entanto, na maioria dos casos (todos?), esses dados são armazenados numa tabela separada do sistema de arquivos **não** afetando em nada o tamanho do arquivo.

Por exemplo: No sistema NTFS que é padrão do Windows XP até Windows 8, é armazenado na "Master File Table";

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra alternativa, nativa a partir do Delphi 2009 ou superior, é a função [`ByteLength`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/SysUtils.ByteLength) da *unit* `SysUtils`.

Veja um exemplo (retirado da documentação):

```
var
  LS1: WideString;

begin
  LS1 := 'Hello World!';
  Writeln('UnicodeString: ''', LS1, ''' contains ', Length(LS1), ' characters in ', ByteLength(LS1), ' bytes.');
  Readln;
end.
```

A saída será:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Como bem [mencionado pelo @EMBarbosa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10517/como-saber-o-tamanho-em-kb-de-uma-string/10740#comment18452_10740) a função `ByteLength` não está disponível para versões inferiores ao Delphi 2009, olhando o código fonte da função `ByteLength` é possível ver que é essencialmente o mesmo código postado [na resposta do EMBarbosa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10624/6454).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
function ByteLength(const S: string): Integer;
begin
Result := Length(S) * SizeOf(Char);
end;
```

Comment: Este método não está disponível no Delphi 7. E ele marcou a pergunta com a tag Delphi-7.

Comment: Ficou joia, quase melhor que a minha. :P :D

Answer (score 0):

Não encontrei resposta simples pra sua primeira pergunta, porém segue:

O que você pode fazer para ter uma ideia do tamanho do seu XML é estressar o seu fonte.

Fiz em 5 minutos um stress test. Provavelmente não vai te servir, por ter parâmetros diferentes do seu xml *(que você não enviou ao fazer a pergunta)*, porém é necessário pra explicar meu argumento. Segue:

```
Var
  XML : IXMLDOCUMENT;
  RootNode, CurNode : IXMLNODE;
  i : integer;
begin
  XML := NewXMLDocument;
  XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
  XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent]; // looks better in Editor ;)
  RootNode := XML.AddChild('XML');
  CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('Teste');
  CurNode := CurNode.AddChild('Test22');
  CurNode.Text := 'Texto Texto Test';
  for I := 0 to 99 do
  begin
    CurNode.Attributes['Novo_Atributo' + IntToStr(i)] := 'Valor';
  end;


  XMl.SaveToFile('C:\teste.xml');
```

Com esse teste percebi algo interessante:

No trecho

```
  for I := 0 to 99 do
  begin
    CurNode.Attributes['Novo_Atributo' + IntToStr(i)] := 'Valor';
  end;
```

Tenho o seguinte tamanho em disco: **4,00 KB (4.096 bytes)**

Trocando o valor do laço de 99 para 199

```
  for I := 0 to 199 do
  begin
    CurNode.Attributes['Novo_Atributo' + IntToStr(i)] := 'Valor';
  end;
```

tenho o seguinte tamanho em disco: **8,00 KB (8.192 bytes)**

A partir daí, não chegar aos seus 500kb se torna uma regra de 3 simples.

Quanto à segunda, a partir do momento em que seu arquivo é salvo, por via de regra nada muda seu tamanho, fique despreocupado.

Answer (score 0):

A interface `IXMLDocument` apresenta uma propriedade chamada `XML`, que é um `TStrings`. Este tipo tem uma propriedade chamada `Text` que é a respresentação em string do documento XML que será gravado. Se você fizer:

```
tamanho := Length(MeuXMLDocument.XML.Text) / SizeOf(Char);
```

terá o tamanho em bytes do documento.